# How can I develop a reduction formula for $\int \sin^n d x$ in 1 step jumps

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to develop a reduction formaula for the integral - $\int \sin^n x dx$.
I've successfully developed a formula which is depended on two elements jumps, which is more or less:

$$\int \sin^k x d x =  \frac{k-1}{k} \int \sin^{k-2}x d x
                        - \frac{1}{k} \cos x  \sin^{k-1} x
$$

This formula however only works on $k-2$ jumps. How can I connect $\int \sin^k x d x$ to $\int sin^{k-1} x d x$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it won't work. $\sin$ and $\cos$ are intimately interwoven, you should look at $\int \sin^n x dx$ and $\int \cos^n x dx$ in parallel. You'll see each leading to the other, and back (your "two steps").

Answer (score 0):

Vonbrand is correct.
If n is even, reducing in steps of 2 will eventually lead to the $\int \sin ^0x\;dx\;$ (or $\int \sin ^2 x \;dx\;$ if you prefer).
If n is odd, you will end up with $\int \sin ^1x\;dx\;$.
Any of these can be found and the problem is solved.