# Spivak Calculus Ch. 19 #15

Tags: calculus, integration

> (a) Find $\int \sin^4 x\, dx$ in two different ways: first using the
>   reduction formula and then using the formula for $\sin^2x$.
>
> (b) Combine your answers to obtain an impressive trigonometric
>   identity.

So, while working on part (a), the power reduction was straight forward enough:

$$\int \sin^4 x\, dx=\int \left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)^2\, dx=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{3}{2}-2\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)\, dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{32}\sin(4x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+\frac{3}{8}x+C.$$

However, I am unsure of what "formula for $\sin^2 x$" the author is referring to here. I initially thought he meant $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$, so I wrote

$$\sin^4 x=\sin^2x(1-\cos^2x)=\sin^2x-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x),$$

and then power reduced those two integrals, but obtained the exact same result. The manipulation

$$\sin^4 x=(1-\cos^2x)^2=1-2\cos^2x+\cos^4x,$$

also ended up giving me the same answer after integration.

I'm assuming that I should arrive at some seemingly different solution for this integral, and then use the fact that the difference of the two expressions must be constant to derive the "impressive trigonometric identity," but I can't seem to find a method of integration that doesn't give an identical result. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use the **reduction** formula again I guess.

Comment: But that doesn't give me the other expression I need for the identity?

Comment: By reduction formaula I mean this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383478/how-can-i-develop-a-reduction-formula-for-int-sinn-d-x-in-1-step-jumps

Comment: You could use integration by parts.

Comment: Ahhh, I confused power reduction with the trick of reducing the power in the integrand with integration by parts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the formula for $\sin^2x$ is the one you used the first time and by "reduction formula", the author means that you should integrate by parts:
$$\int\sin^n\mathrm dx = -\cos x\sin^{n-1} x + (n-1)\int\cos^2x\sin^{n-2}x\mathrm dx$$
I think the above is mostly right although I'm not sure it's absolutely correct